# Add carousel control (next - prev) automaticlly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have more than one bootstrap carousel in my project and I want to reduce my html elements I remove my `carousel-indicators` and I added with js.I want to do same thing for `carousel-control` but my head is swollen how can I adapt my code

```js
var myCarousels = $(".carousel");
  myCarousels.each(function( index, element  ) {
    var myCarousel = $("#"+$(element).attr('id')); 
    myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
    var indicators = $("#"+$(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-indicators"); 
    $("#"+$(element).attr('id') +" .carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
      (index === 0) ? 
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#"+$(element).attr('id')+"' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>") : 
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#"+$(element).attr('id')+"' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/87D3/production/_84817743_beckhamfashion.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/9949/production/_84814293_dummy.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my english is bad I mean My head is swollen

Comment: That really doesn't help to clarify the question.

Comment: in my example there are carousel control buttons bootstrap carousel has next and prev button to control carousel and I want to add this code with js not with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` controls inside of `myCarousel`:

```js
var myCarousels = $(".carousel");
myCarousels.each(function(index, element) {
  var myCarousel = $("#" + $(element).attr('id'));
  myCarousel.append('<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');
  var indicators = $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-indicators");
  $("#" + $(element).attr('id') + " .carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
    (index === 0) ?
    indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "' class='active'></li>"):
      indicators.append("<li data-target='#" + $(element).attr('id') + "' data-slide-to='" + index + "'></li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/87D3/production/_84817743_beckhamfashion.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/9949/production/_84814293_dummy.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could we make a href dynamic ?